# Ajax post in laravel return error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

This is my test ajax in laravel (refer below)

```
$.ajaxSetup({                            
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')                          
    } 
});
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){    
    var playlist = $("#playlist").val();  
    var id = '{{$data->id}}'                      
    e.preventDefault();           
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',                            
        url:'/ajaxRequest', 
        data:{playlist:playlist,id:id },                            
        success:function(data){                            
            alert(data.success);                            
        }                            
    }); 
});
```

This is my Controller in laravel (refer below)

```
$playlist = $request->input('playlist');
$id = $request->input('id');
$playlist = Playlist::find($playlist);
$songs = $playlist->songs()->get();        
foreach ($songs as $song){
    if($id == $song->id){
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Sond Allready added']);
    }
}
$song = Song::findOrFail($id);
$playlist->songs()->attach($song);
return response()->json(['success'=>'Playlist Updated Success']);
```

But it gives me error when I run the console in google chrome and it doesnt return the expected response **"return 'Success! ajax in laravel 5';"**

whats wrong/problem to my code? anything i am missing?

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajaxRequest 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Have you verified if the route really exists ?

Comment: @Buddika add your web.file in question

Comment: is this `$request->input('playlist');` an integer?

Comment: Open your chrome developer tools and check the network tab. Reload the request until you get your 500 error. Then on the network tab of your chrome browser you can see what the actual 500 (internal server error) is.
Copy and paste that error here, so we can help you some more

Comment: Check the server's error.log, it usually contains useful information that leads you directly to the problem.

Comment: Route::post('ajaxRequest', 'SongController@ajaxRequestPost');

Comment: This code work for form submit

Answer (score 1):

Add error handling code to your ajax and see what error it's throwing !

`error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}`